# How to add user in a group in windows vista home

Tags: windows-vista, user-accounts

How to add user in a group in windows vista home?

Comment: we need more details...

Comment: @studiohack what more details do you need? looking at vista home now, there is no "local users and groups" it's missing from 'computer management'. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e3d50d7f-deba-4a79-b347-72ed3d14d940/local-users-and-groups-in-vista-home-premium-not-available?forum=itprovistasecurity     you know some versions of windows are crippled.. ever hear anything about windows 7 starter being bad for that kind of reason? `vista home` doesn't sound high end does it xp home was perhaps or probably crippled too.  7 starter very much so.so no surprise re vista home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a command prompt:

```
net localgroup NameOfGroup UserName1 UserName2 /add
```